# Why should refractive index of core be higher than that of cladding in TIR?

Tags: geometric-optics

> To confine the optical signal in the core, the refractive index of the core must be higher than that of the cladding.

I failed to understand how and why does cladding refractive index matter since total internal reflection will only depend on the refractive index of the core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, your last sentence is not correct.  Suppose, for example, that the cladding is very thick and has exactly the same index as the core.  Light in the core will not "see" the boundary between the core and cladding, so will exit the core and pass into the cladding.  In effect, the radius of the core has been increased by the thickness of the cladding.

TIR requires a difference in the refractive indices of two media.  At less than a critical angle, light incident on the interface *from the high index side* will be totally reflected.  That critical angle is the angle at which the refracted ray would be refracted into the lower-index medium into an angle parallel to any line in the interface.  See Snell's law in wikipedia.